# Passing argument array to CasperJS from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using CasperJS to test a website. A part of the test is resource check.

What I want to do:

Pass array or object array to CasperJS and iterate through them.
The first step is one array then object array. both have same issue.

Node.js code:

```
require('child_process').exec('/usr/local/bin/casperjs script.js [url,regex]' , function(err, stdout, stderr) {  
    err && console.log(err);
    stderr && console.log(stderr.toString());
    stdout && console.log(stdout.toString());
})
```

Casperjs script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create(),
    a = casper.cli.args[0],
    // we need something here to string to js array
    w=a[0],
    r=a[1];
casper.start(w, function() {
    if (this.resourceExists(r)) {
        console.log("PASS\t" +r+ "\t"+ w);
    } else {
        console.log("FAIL\t" +r+ "\t"+ w);
    }
});
casper.run();
```

The problem is CasperJS takes args as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better approach to problem:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/bhA81OyHA7s

Passing variables as options. Works like a charm

---

My Final nodejs:

```
var exec = require('child_process'),

array = [
    {url:"",regex:""}
];


for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var url = array[i]["url"];
    var regex = array[i]["regex"];
    exec.exec('/usr/local/bin/casperjs casper2.js --url="'+url+'" --regex="'+regex+'" ' , function(err, stdout, stderr) {  
        err && console.log(err);
        stderr && console.log(stderr.toString());
        stdout && console.log(stdout.toString());
    });
};
```

In CasperJS

```
w=casper.cli.get("url"),
reg= casper.cli.get("regex"),
rpart = reg.split("/"),
r=new RegExp(rpart[1],rpart[2]);
casper.start(w, function() {
    if (this.resourceExists(r)) {
        console.log("PASS\t" +r+ "\t"+ w);
    } else {
        console.log("FAIL\t" +r+ "\t"+ w);
    }
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: How would you handle arrays using this?

Comment: That's not what I meant, but you know your requirements better than I do. Don't run many processes in a loop, because you may not have enough resources to do so. Use something like [`async.parallelLimit()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallellimittasks-limit-callback).

Answer (score 1):

When you call it like that:

```
'/usr/local/bin/casperjs script.js "[\''+yourURL+'\',\''+yourRegex+'\']"'
```

You could simply use

```
a = JSON.parse(casper.cli.args[0]),
w = a[0],
r = new RegExp(a[1]);
```

If `casper.cli.args[0]` is actually JSON, then it can be parsed as such. `resourceExists()` takes regular expressions only as `RegExp` objects.

---

A better way if the data that you pass gets too long, then you should write the data to a temporary file with node.js' fs module and read it with PhantomJS' fs module, parsing it along the way.

Comment: i can use like
'/usr/local/bin/casperjs casper2.js ['+url+','+regex+']' other wise gives error 
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was in a hurry and didn't check the quotes.